# java.io.ioexception unexpected end of stream on connection retrofit android

Tags: android, rest, api, retrofit2, jsonparser

[image]

***In this activity:-*
on category spinner item selected to  retrofit call for products
when I changed category slowly then no problem
but when I change category fastly then this error show.
any solution?**

Comment: You need to use caching with Retrofit.

Comment: https://medium.com/@bapspatil/caching-with-retrofit-store-responses-offline-71439ed32fda

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of your swift action of changing the categories in spinner. On each category change there will be a network request.

What you can do is either check and cancel ongoing `network` requests or do not allow changing categories when a network request is already in progress.